# How would I generate a css, js and html file using php?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

How would i generate a file of all of the following types:

.js
.css
.html

I would also need to be able to read the file and overwrite it somehow.

Is this possible in anyway?

All of these files are just text files with different file extensions so if I could maybe make a text file and change the file extension?

Comment: Why do you think this is a good idea?

Comment: seems irrelevant, but i am trying to make a website for myself where i can save, edit, and run html, css, and js files.

Comment: Generating HTML from PHP is fine but generating CSS and JS breaks the browser's ability to cache these files, leading to a slower user experience.

Comment: @Diodeus not really 100% relevant to the question, but I'm curious why you think generating CSS and JS with PHP would affect browser caching in any way. This is governed by the server headers, which shouldn't be any different - if they are they'll be set by your PHP script so you have complete control.

Comment: You end up sending the HTML+CSS+JS with each ADDITIONAL page. Sure, you can cache the first page, it won't help you on the next page. The proper way the CSS+JS will be cached with the first request and will not have to be sent on subsequent ones. Your CSS+JS likely won't change page-to-page, so why carry the extra traffic burden?

Comment: this is personal. i don't care at all about cache.....

Comment: your could also simply name your css and js files with a .php extension if you want them to be parsed by PHP prior to output (generated). `<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.php"></script>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As all of those are simply text files, all you need to do is create/open the file with the desired name and write text into them.

Check out some of the PHP file IO commands:

- [fopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)
- [fread()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php)
- [fwrite()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)
- [fclose()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php)

Comment: thanks. probably should have looked harder; i've used those before. which function do i use to create the file and give it a name?

Comment: Read the info for `fopen()` and specifically its `mode` parameter. The functions are well documented and have examples of their usage.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is usually (often?) used as a templating language, where HTML "files" are generated "on-the-fly" and output directly to the browser.

I could be wrong, but it sounds like you are talking about generating files and saving them to disk to be served statically to the browser later. If that's the case, you're right - they are just text-files - so writing them as text-files with the relevant file extension should work.

This seems like it would be logistically complicated to manage as a site scales though. Also - if you're creating an web-interface to edit files on the server, while some CMS-es do this (Wordpress for example), it does come with a lot of security issues (allowing PHP unrestricted write access to your server is rarely a good move).

Comment: it's personal so it's not a matter of security. how would i do this though? could you link me to examples of how to create a text file with a given extension, read it (as in get the contents), and write to it (as in overwrite the contents)

Comment: @maxhud Not sure what you mean by "it's personal" - if it's web-facing, security is always an issue. As far as reading/writing files using PHP, Herohtar has answered you there.